# What does ぎゃんかわ女子 mean?

Tags: translation, slang

From the lyrics from [this song](https://lyricstranslate.com/ja/camellia-%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%9F%E7%AC%91-lyrics.html) say the following:

> ねぇねぇ君～　そこのぎゃんかわ女子～

I'm having trouble figuring out what "ぎゃんかわ" means. Is maybe this is a conjugation of a verb that I don't recognize? Maybe a grammer point that I am not familar with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ぎゃんかわ is slang for “really cute”.

> ぎゃんかわ → とても可愛{かわ}いい

Comment: Thanks, is there a general "conjugation rule" I can learn here for the slang?
For instance do other ii-verbs also have this slang, what other other adjectives (verbs and nowns)?

Comment: ギャン generally means とても but I feel its idiomatic usage is fairly limited. ギャン泣き comes to mind. That said I think other compounds like ギャンこわ etc would be understandable. Either way, something noun-like comes after it.

Comment: Though I guess the ギャン in ギャン泣き might actually be slightly different...

Comment: https://minnkane.com/news/3504 claims it could be from Fukuoka

Comment: https://dic.pixiv.net/a/ぎゃんかわ Pixiv too